How do I unshield and shield apps with Screen Time API?
So I already made it possible to unshield and shield a specific app if you hit the primary button of the shield configuration.
class ShieldActionExtension: ShieldActionDelegate {
    override func handle(action: ShieldAction, for application: ApplicationToken, completionHandler: @escaping (ShieldActionResponse) -> Void) {
        switch action {
        case .primaryButtonPressed:
            
            unlockandreapply(for: application)
            completionHandler(.none)
        case .secondaryButtonPressed:
            
            completionHandler(.none)
        @unknown default:
            fatalError()
        }
    }
    
    func unlockandreapply(for application: ApplicationToken)
    {
        unlockApp(for: application)
        
        // Schedule timer to reshield after 10 seconds
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10) {
            self.reapplyShield(for: application)
            
            
        }
    }
    private func unlockApp(for application: ApplicationToken) {
        let store = ManagedSettingsStore()
        store.shield.applications?.remove(application)
        print("App \(application) is unshielded")
    }
    
    // Reapplies the shield to the application
    private func reapplyShield(for application: ApplicationToken) {
        let store = ManagedSettingsStore()
        
        // Create a new shield configuration if necessary
        if store.shield.applications == nil {
            store.shield.applications = [application]
        } else {
            store.shield.applications?.insert(application)
        }
        print("Shield reapplied to application with token \(application)")
    }
} 

However is it possible to unshield and shield apps outside of The Shield action extension? Until now I could only get the unshielding to work outside of the extension, but the reshielding never worked in the background, this only worked inside of the extension. My goal is to have a button in my own app which then could unshield and reshield perfectly in the background just like my current primary button of the shield configuration...
